# how to create a http server that would handle http requests

Tags: http, post, httpwebrequest

I am aware of apache web server, i can host web pages.

how to create a http page(server) that would handle http post requests and respond to those requests.

Answer (score 2):

If you just want something simple, try [node.js](http://nodejs.org/)

You can write the server code in javascript.  Otherwise, you can just use PHP or another scripting language with Apache web server, just make sure you enable the PHP module (or whichever module you need)

Comment: i got php module enabled, could you please explain how do i do that with manual scripts like php/simple html/perl/ruby?

Comment: If you put a file in the apache web server's html directory it should be able to serve it correctly.  If you use the .php extension, the web server will automatically hand off the file to the php interpreter.